# Migrating EF Code First in multiple instances

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I have an MVC app that using EF6 Code First. I want to deploy this app to multiple datacenters. On deployments that have migrations, I can write a script to migrate them all as simultaneously as possible, but if one datacenter is slower, then the calls could all be rejected since the schema no longer matches. A script that tried to coordinate would also make rolling upgrades impossible.

Is there a way to make EF at least attempt to run the query even though the schemas don't match? Is there a different way I can/should approach this?

**UPDATE:**

Let's see if I can word this better. I want to have my MVC app in multiple datacenters. Let's assume that I deploy the app to each datacenter individually.

Option 1

1. Deploy to DC A
2. Code first migration runs on centralized DB
3. Requests made to DC A succeed, but requests to DC B fail

Option 2

1. Deploy to DC A
2. Do not automatically run migration
3. Requests made to DC A fail and requests to DC B continue to succeed

How do I develop a deployment strategy that will make it so that requests to either DC will work?

BTW: I am using Azure Web Sites, if a platform-specific solution is needed.

Comment: "runs on centralized DB" Migrations apply to the database, not to the application instance. If your schema has changed then you would need to deploy updated code for each application, but you don't have to run a migration for each.  The migration only applies to the centralized database.

Comment: Also, I believe EF checks the DB version and will fail if its version differs(it did a couple versions ago but I know they got rid of some of the migrations metadata tables).  So your second application instance will simply throw errors for any requests made to it while you are deploying the updated instance, which is usually pretty fast.  You could test this and determine the exact exception and trap that exception and send users to "site being updated" message or try to direct them to a different instance if you have that capability.

Comment: Yep, you've hit it on the head. I can totally return errors or a "site being updated" message, but it seems like there should be a solution for rolling upgrades, where you test the site on a limited number of servers before sending it to the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your post, it seemed like you were concerned with how it would behave during the actual upgrade.  Nothing about testing.  But in comments you are asking about doing a partial deployment then doing testing.  So on one hand you'd want to deploy as quickly as possible to minimize downtime.  On the other hand, it sounds like you want to deploy to one site, test, and have the other sites continue to function while you are verifying the first deployment?
Verifying a deployment is reasonable, but fairly complex.  I'm not sure you will find much in the way of automation for this.  **I think you should test prior to production deployment thoroughly, and then simply deploy as quickly as possible in production.**  If there were an issue you found only when deploying to production, you'd be in a bad situation, because now your site is down until you can fix it.  Even if you could get the other instance to work with the new database, that is risky as it is going to be modifying things against a schema it doesn't completely understand.  Additionally, if you do need to rollback the DDL then you will almost certainly lose any data that was modified since the deployment.  So it is really best that all instances for the old schema fail until they are upgraded, to prevent them from modifying data that is at risk of being lost.

Usually you should have done a deployment to a staging environment that is as close to your production as possible to test the database migration process.  This is called pre-production testing, and sometimes involves restoring the most recent backup from production into staging to ensure new constraints/structures are valid for existing data.  By deploying to this staging environment, you should have a very high level of confidence that production deployment will go successfully.

You additionally safe guard yourself against production deployment issues by taking backups prior to deployment so that you can rollback as necesary(although this is worst case scenario as it might mean throwing out important data that came in between backup/deployment and realization that there is an issue).  I imagine EF migrations uses a transaction to run the DDL scripts so they should rollback all-or-nothing if there is an issue.

Comment: Testing is just one example of how rolling upgrades are used. Microsoft does this for Outlook.com, Bing, etc. It's a last minute sanity check so you aren't affecting everyone if something was unaccounted for in production. They talk about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj717232.aspx).

Comment: Rolling upgrades can work if you are using straight SQL as you can split the update into multiple updates that each know about each other, but given I'm a one-man team, this is probably not worth pursuing and simple give a better error message. Not enough bang for the buck.

Comment: I think rolling upgrades in the context of the Azure articles is simply dealing with changes to the application in individual instances.  It sounds awesome until you consider a centralized DB that has frequent schema changes.  I find alot of those kinds of features don't stand up to real world challenges very well.  Outlook probably has their database heavily partitioned, so they can upgrade a single database instance at the same time they upgrade the set of servers for that particular database instance, and leave other db instances/servers untouched.